# Multiplying a dataframe by a larger one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` with the same columns but not the same row number.

I want to multiply them element-wise such that the smallest one (`df1`) fits into the first corresponding rows of the largest one (`df2`), and gives `0` for the remaining cells. I tried `df1.mul(df2)` but this gave me a DataFrame full of NaNs.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Can you share an example of your inputs and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just multiply the two dataframes, the missing rows will be filled with `NaN` values (missing values. You can then simply replace all these with `0.0`, or any value.

Here is an example:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(range(6), columns=["A"])

In [3]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(range(8), columns=["A"])   # different length

In [4]: df3 = df1 * df2

In [5]: df3   # Look at the Not-a-Number values
Out[5]:
      A
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   4.0
3   9.0
4  16.0
5  25.0
6   NaN
7   NaN

In [6]: df3.fillna(0.0)   # fill those NaN values with zero
Out[6]:
      A
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   4.0
3   9.0
4  16.0
5  25.0
6   0.0
7   0.0
```